# ASP.NET Excel Manipulation FREE Library

Tags: asp.net, excel

I was looking for a free ASP.net way to handle Excel files. I searched the internet and all I found was the paid versions, I would have paid but I work as a part time freelancer and the excel libraries are a bit costly. :(

I have been using PHP and PHPExcel library is what I have been using for excel manipulation in PHP.

My recent project has made me switch to ASP.NET and I urgently need free ASP.NET method of doing it. Free library is what I am looking for.

Comment: Have you looked at related questions? for example http://stackoverflow.com/a/2603625/724944 It recommends EppPlus which is also my choice when it comes to Excel manipulation. It doesn't matter if you use it in ASP.NET or in plain .NET..

Comment: I did look at EppPlus but it does not support excel 97-2003(.xls) I guess? I need it to be .xls and .xlsx both.

Comment: Then you can try http://npoi.codeplex.com/, but support for Excel 2007 is still in beta.

Comment: Is interop a bad choice? As answered by the guy below?

Comment: It depends. If you expect high performance, reliability and low memory consumption, then I'd avoid interop. Try the library and see if it fits your requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28795/Very-Simple-Library-to-Work-with-Excel-in-NET

Try this out, this is actually INTEROP based, and requires Microsoft Office (excel) to be installed on the webserver.

Comment: I am using my laptop for development. So having office is not a problem.

Comment: Actually I mentioed about webserver. You will finally deploy this on a production server or the server of your client (right?), so just make sure that you have MS Office installed there.

Comment: Great! This is what I wanted!